# Remove all elements of a type before an element of a different type

Tags: javascript

How can I remove all elements of a type before an element of a different type?

For example, in the following string, I want to remove any `<br>` elements which occur before the first `<p>` element.

Sample input:

```
var myString = "<br><br><br><br><p>Hello there!</p><br><br><br><br>";
```

Expected output:

```
var myString = "<p>Hello there!</p><br><br><br><br>";
```

Comment: How meaning? you want to do it in what way? Shell script or Perl or using what?

Comment: You mean all the `<br>` tags before `<p>Hello there!</p>` ?

Comment: Thanks for updating my question @TinyGiant!

Comment: Your welcome, we had some users want to close it for various reasons, I thought I would make it as clear as possible, and as useful for future viewers as I could. I edited my answer as well, now that I'm actually awake.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're working with HTML, you should utilize an HTML parser. Sure the string that you supplied may be straight forward and simple, but accounting for different variations of the HTML will complicate your script if you're using RegExp or string functions. Let the HTML parser do the hard work for you, then use the existing functions to achieve your goal.

You can utilize the browser's HTML parser with the [Native DOM API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model):

- Create a temporary element (but you don't have to append it to the document) using [`document.createElement()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement).
- Pass your string to the [`Element.innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property of the newly created element.

Now you've turned your string into HTML, we can use the Native DOM API methods to work with it.

The next step is to get a list of child nodes for the newly created element using the [`Node.childNodes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes) property. This property returns a live list, so adding or removing items will update the list, which means that we cannot iterate through the list in the same way you would a non-live list.

I use a while loop which will continue as long as there are elements in the in the list, and there is an element at the current index.

Then we perform a few checks against the [`Element.tagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName) (which will return in uppercase):

- If we reach a the requested `stop` element, we should exit the loop.
- If we hit an element that is not an element of the type that we want to remove, we should skip it.

If the current element passes those checks, remove it.

Once the loop is finished, return the resulting HTML string.

```js
function trimLeadingBreaks(string, remove, stop) {
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.innerHTML = string;
  
    var children = div.childNodes;
    var index = 0;

    while(children.length && !!children[index]) {
        if(children[index].tagName === stop) break;
        if(children[index].tagName !== remove && ++index) continue;

        div.removeChild(children[index]);
    }
  
    return div.innerHTML;
}

function demo(string, remove, stop) {
    var trimmed = trimLeadingBreaks(string, remove, stop);
    document.getElementById('result').textContent += trimmed + "\n";
    return demo;
}

demo('<br><br><br><br><p>Hello there!</p><br><br><br><br>', 'BR', 'P')
    ('<br><br><i></i><br><br><p>Hello there!</p><br><br><br><br>', 'BR', 'P')
    ('<br><br><i></i><br><br><p>Hello there!</p><br><br><br><br>', 'I', 'P');
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

**Further Reading**:

- [Document Object Model (DOM)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model)
- [Document.createElement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createElement)
- [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML)
- [Node.childNodes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/childNodes)
- [Element.tagName](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/tagName)

Answer (score 2):

```
$("p:first").prevAll("br").remove();
```

**(UPDATED )** And if you have a string:

```
$("<div>"+myString+"</div>").find("p:first").prevAll("br").remove();
```

Treating it as a plain text instead of jQuery Object

```
var arr = '<br><br><br><br><p>text</p><br><p>text121</p>'.split("<p>");
arr.splice(0,1);
arr.join("<p>");
```